# OpenLayers: How to re-add a feature that draws line segments of a tracked route?

Tags: openlayers, vue.js

My app records tracks (e.g. a bike route). There is a start and a stop button, which start and stop the recording of such a track. After a recording has been stopped, the user can start a new recording again. And here start the troubles: When recording again, the LineString ist not drawn again.

Here is the relevant code:

When the recording is started, these things happen;

```js
// in Vue methods
// "this.trackFeature", "this.trackLayer" etc are defined in Vue's "data"
// and setup in the "mounted()" lifecycle

startRecording () {
  // Create / add trackLayer if there isn't any
  if (!this.trackLayerAdded) {
    this.trackFeature = new Feature({
      geometry: new LineString([])
    })

    this.trackSource.addFeature(this.trackFeature)
    this.trackLayer.setSource(this.trackSource)
    this.trackLayer.setStyle(this.trackStyle)


    // Check if "this.trackLayer" has already been added, otherwise
    // openlayers' "reassign" error (58) is thrown 
    let trackLayerExists = null
    const layerCollection = this.olMap.getLayers()
    layerCollection.forEach(l => {
      if (l.ol_uid === this.trackLayer.ol_uid) {
        trackLayerExists = l
      }
    })

    // If the "trackLayer" was not found, add it
    if (!trackLayerExists) {
      this.olMap.addLayer(this.trackLayer)
    }

    this.trackLayerAdded = true
  }
}
```

Since the line style is defined with `{ radius: 30, fill: [_yellow in rgba_] }, a big yellow point appears on the screen on my desktop computer (where the` geolocation` does not move).

When the recording is stopped and saved, this happens:

```js
// in Vue methods
deleteTrack () {
  this.trackSource.removeFeature(this.trackFeature)
  this.trackSource.clear()
  this.trackFeature = null // needed?
  
  // // Do I have to remove the layer, too?
  // this.olMap.removeLayer(this.trackLayer)

  this.trackLayerAdded = false
},
```

The yellow line segment disappears.

Now, when I click on "start" again to record a new route, the yellow LineString does NOT appear anymore, which is, what I would have expected.

I cannot find my mistake. What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do that each time I click on "start record" a new LineString will be recorded?